# jQuery's `this` and `this` in the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've code like the following:

```html
function tell(){
  console.log(this==window);//true
  console.log($(el).html());
}

$('.elem').click(function(){
  el=this;
  console.log($(this).html());
  tell();
});
```

I want to know why `tell()`s `this`  is not  `this` from the click event handler anonymous function?

Comment: You need to provide the right scope```tell.call(this)```

Comment: Sounds like you just need to read some basic JavaScript tutorials on how `this` is defined.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: @Gothdo: `this` doesn't reflect a scope, and its value is based on the call, not on where the function is defined.